# Combine 2 SQL "Complex" Queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I don't know if these are "complex queries" by defn, but they look very complex to a noob like me.

So I have a query here that will get the latest chart of customer_id=5:

```
$query = "SELECT c.Chart_ID, c.Chart_Notes
          FROM tblchart AS c WHERE c.Customer_ID=5
          ORDER BY c.Last_Edited ASC LIMIT 1";
```

But I have to relate it to another table that uses the `Chart_ID` as foreign key. How can I get the data from the `tblcontent` using `tblchart.Chart_ID=tblcontent.Chart_ID`? I couldn't just add that as:

```
$query = "SELECT c.Chart_ID, c.Chart_Notes, d.Content_Desc, d.Content_Title
          FROM tblchart AS c, tblcontent AS d
          WHERE c.Customer_ID=5 AND c.Chart_ID=d.Chart_ID
          ORDER BY c.Last_Edited DESC LIMIT 1";
```

can I? As that would limit the search to just one...the use of `LIMIT 1` is just to get the latest, but for the subsequent query (extended query), I am expecting multiple results extracted from `tblcontent` in addition to the first query I posted. A join, maybe, or union, or a complex query, but how? Please, can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: whats wrong with using second query without using limit? it will include the result that you get from first query as well. Also, if `c.Last_Edited` date field, to get latest entry you should `ORDER IT BY DESCENDING ORDER USING DESC`.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to change it back when testing. It's supposed to be DESC. And..wouldn't that show ALL charts (just arranged in desc order)? I just want to see the LATEST chart with its tied up tblcontents. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.Chart_ID, a.Chart_Notes, c.Content_Desc, c.Content_Title
FROM    tblChart a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT Chart_ID, MAX(Last_edited) maxEdited
            FROM tblChart
            GROUP BY Chart_ID
        ) b ON a.Chart_ID = b.Chart_ID AND
                a.Last_Edited = b.maxEdited
        INNER JOIN tblcontent c
            ON a.Chart_ID = c.Chart_ID
WHERE   a.Customer_ID=5
```